# Using private svn+bower doesn't work in dockerfile

Tags: svn, docker, bower

I've been trying to use docker to run my development environment.
My stack have a private bower registry that needs a `.bowerrc` in my `$HOME`.

The format of my .bowerrc file it's:

**/home/.bowerrc** (inside my docker mounted as volume)

```
{
  "registry": "https://<user>:<password>@bower.mycompany.com",
  "timeout": 300000,
  "strict-ssl": false
}
```

The way of I mount this file in my docker file was using this command:

```
docker run -it --net='host' -v $(pwd):/home/dev/app -v /home/USER/.dockershared/.bowerrc:/home/.bowerrc --name="myproject" --privileged bower-gulp:node0.12
```

My Dockerfile have been built for support a environment that use bower, gulp and svn. This is the **`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM node:0.12-wheezy
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash dev
RUN chown -R dev:dev /home/dev
USER dev
ENV HOME /home/dev
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/dev/.npm-global/bin"
WORKDIR /home/dev/app

RUN mkdir /home/dev/.npm-global && \
    npm config set prefix '/home/dev/.npm-global' && \
    npm install -g bower gulp && \
    apt-get install subversion

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash"]
```

My **`package.json`** file that use `bower install` command is like this:

```
{
    "name": "my_project",
    "version": "3.1.3",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "repository": {
        "type": "svn",
        "url": "https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/My_repo"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "bower": "1.x",
        "del": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp": "3.x",
        "gulp-maven-deploy": "^0.2.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-template": "^3.1.0",
        "node-rest-client": "^1.8.0",
        "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
        "svn-npm-crutch": "0.x"
    },
    "svnDependencies": {
        "framework-tools-build": "https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/tools/build/trunk",
        "framework-tools-functional-testing": "https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/tools/functional-testing/trunk"

    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.8.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "install": "bower install -F --allow-root && node ./node_modules/svn-npm-crutch/lib/svn-npm-crutch.js",
        "demo-mode": "gulp functional-test --browser=chrome --demo"
    },
    "config": {
        "unsafe-perm": true
    }
}
```

Finally, when i try `npm install` or `bower install` I get this error:

```
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "svn list https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/ui/common/tags --verbose --non-interactive", exit code of #1 svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/ui/common/tags': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://svn.mycompany.com)

Additional error details:
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/ui/common/tags': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://svn.mycompany.com)
```

**Anybody can help me to understand this?**

Comment: Do you need to do anything special to log into SVN?

Comment: No, only set my user and password in my `.bowerrc` file. When I try this in my host machine, this works fine, but inside in my docker container isn't =(

Comment: Silly question, are you sure `--net='host'` is correct with single quotes? I never use it with quotes. Does the container actually use the host's network stack?

Comment: @Grif-fin finally i fix this. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I understand the problem.

The SVN certificate should be accepted inside the docker container.
For to do this, inside the docker container, entering using the interactive-attach mode `-ia` and using a entry point the `/bin/bash` console, I ran this command:

`svn info <any_svn_respository_of_my_company>`

example

`svn info https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/ui/common/`.

Then I accepted the certificate and all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to users id difference between your docker and your host machine. So it results in docker not being able to read the files necessaries to login.

To know your user id (UID), on the host and docker run: `id -u $USER`

If they are different, I would re-build the image and create a user inside the docker image as follows: `useradd -u 999 USERNAME` where 999 must be the user's UID owning your credentials from you host machine, the username can differ.

Hope that solves your problem, Regards!

Comment: when i try this, the build of the image gets stuck.

Comment: I tried on my machine and everything went ok. I tried `RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 1001 dev`.